# How can I create a loop with my conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

i am looking for help. We need to write a program that prints all numbers in the range of (n -20,n + 20). In addition, the program asks you beforehand to input a number. If that number is not even or multiple of 10, you need to take a guess again. Only if the number is even and multiple by 10 the program prints the range aforementioned. I struggle with that.

I came up with that solution:

```
    i = int(input("please enter a number: "))
    while (i % 10 == 0) and ((i % 2) == 0):
        x = 20
        while (x >= 0):
            print(i - x)
            x = x - 1
        break
```

but it will only print the range n-20 and not +20 and it also won't ask you again if you input a false number.

I know there is also the possibility to use for I in range() but I am at a loss for ideas at the moment.

Thank you!

Comment: everything that is multiple of 10 is even. One of your conditions is redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
while True:
  i = int(input("please enter a number: "))
  if i % 10 == 0:
       for x in range(i-20,i+21):
           print(x)
       break
```

It will keep on asking until it satisfies the condition.

Comment: thanks! I came up with that in the time. while True: print("Welcome at my guessing game.") i = int(input("Please enter a number: ")) if i % 10 == 0 and i % 2 == 0: continue //. In our teachers example continue will bring us back to the beginning of the loop. After that I wanted to define the range or at least try. in your case why does it keep asking until it satisfies the condition?

Comment: You can change according to your need, I have put `while True:` so that it keeps on asking until a number which is divisible by 10 is met. If it satisfies the condition; it will pass the if condition and enter for loop; Once all the integers are printed; it will break from the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Better make use of `range`, something like:

```
x = 20
for number in range(i - x, i + x + 1):
    print(number)
```

Note: `range(1, 5)` creates a generator which yields the numbers 1 to 4, excluding 5. Thus the `i + 20 + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Doing it the hard way: you want to start from `i-20`, so:

```
n = i - 20
```

and go to `i+20`, so:

```
while n < i+20:
    print(n)
    n += 1
```

All there is to it.

Or, the easy way, aka one liner using range

```
print(range(i-20, i+20), sep="\n")
```

Start with

```
i = 1
while not (i % 10 == 0):
    i = int(input("please enter a number: "))
```

to keep asking until valid input is entered and the problem is solved.